# Mathematica assumptions

Tags: assumptions

Mathematica produces the answer to integral((x + 5)/(x^2 + x − 2) dx). Find what is missing and explain
what assumptions it seems that Mathematica is making.

Comment: Your question looks like a homework problem. This site is not a free homework solver.

Comment: Look at [`FunctionDomain`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionDomain.html)

Comment: Give an example of an "assumption" relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take an attempt at this.

> Find what is missing

```
ClearAll[x]
Apart[(x + 5)/(x^2 + x - 2)]
```

$$
\frac{2}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x+2}
$$

```
Integrate[%, x]
```

$$
2 \log (1-x)-\log (x+2)
$$

One thing is missing is the constant of integration. This can be added like this

```
  Integrate[(x + 5)/(x^2 + x - 2), x, GeneratedParameters -> C]
```

$$
2 \log (1-x)-\log (x+2)+c_1
$$

> explain what assumptions it seems that Mathematica is making.

Since the anti derivative should be

$$
2 \log (| 1-x| )-\log (| x+2| )+c_1
$$

Then Mathematica is making the assumption that $1-x$ and $x+2$ are positive because it is not showing the absolute signs in the result (should this be in the what missing part?).

Which means it assumed that $-2<x<1$.

But all CAS systems I know do the same. They all return the antiderivative of $\int{\frac{1}{x} \,dx}$ as $\ln x$ and not as $\ln|x|$.

Comment: Aren't the absolute signs usually there due to ignorance of logarithms of negative numbers? If one assumes knowledge of complex analysis, there is no really need for it.

Comment: @swish I think you are correct. But at school the teacher keeps taking points everytime I forget to add absolute sign around argument of log when I do integrations. Textbooks also tell us to add absolute sign. May be because we all assume we want result to be in the real domain.  But your point is well taken.